# How to take screenshots of a list of URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, screenshot, browser-plugin

I need to save thumbnail-sized screenshots of about 20 intranet pages and repeat every week.

I ruled out using an online service because the screenshots are business information.

I ruled out installing an application because my office uses both Windows and Mac OS. I didn't want to rely on an application some of us can't install.

I couldn't find a Chrome extension that accepts a list of URLs. I only found extensions that save a screenshot of one open page, not a batch.

Are there other ways?

Comment: FireShot extension does take the list of URLs built option now https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/take-webpage-screenshots/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there other ways?

You may want to consider using Chrome in `--headless` (GUI-less) mode (available since version 59+). Firefox has had a similar feature since version 56+.

Combined with the `--headless` option in Chrome (or `-headless` in Firefox), you can use the `--screenshot` option ([since Firefox 57](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode)) to take screenshots of a website from the command line. These features should be supported on both Windows and MacOS, assuming you are using the current versions of each browser.

**Chrome on Windows**

As an example of using Chrome on Windows to capture a web page, you could use the following command to take a screenshot of e.g. http://example.com:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --screenshot="C:\path\to\screenshot.png" http://example.com/
```

**Chrome on MacOS**

Likewise, you should be able to use a similar command with Chrome on MacOS:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --screenshot http://example.com/
```

Note that simply using `chrome` (above) seems to generally rely on having an appropriate `alias` e.g.:

```
alias chrome="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
```

**Additional Options**

- *--print-to-pdf* — creates a `.pdf` version of a web page e.g. `--print-to-pdf="C:\path\to\output.pdf"`
- *--window-size* — specify an exact window size to render for screenshots, etc. e.g. `--window-size=1366,768`
- *--hide-scrollbars* — removes any scroll bars that might otherwise be rendered in a screenshot, etc. (due to a small viewport).

An updated list of additional switches is available [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

**Headless Chrome Pitfalls**

- On Windows, Chrome seems *extremely* picky regarding paths. To avoid odd behaviors (or outright failures), make sure to always specify a *full path + file name*. This applies to `--screenshot` and `--print-to-pdf` particularly, but even putting Chrome in your Windows PATH/Path and simply using `chrome` (ala MacOS) could lead to issues (especially in batch files).
- Individual pages take individual times to render. For example, a screenshot of https://example.com was created nearly instantaneously on a test system, whereas https://superuser.com consistently took around thirty seconds or longer to render.
- Using `--screenshot` without `--headless` could cause issues with capturing multiple screenshots.
- Screenshots are captured as `.png` files, regardless of image extension (i.e. no `.jpg` files).
- If there is content you wish to capture that isn't being captured, try adjusting the `--window-size` option. Note, however, that capturing "full" (scrolling) web pages may be problematic (at least in theory), so you may have to dig into more complex solutions later, depending upon circumstances.
- Capturing screenshots works best with more "traditional" web pages. Web applications may produce undesirable results.

> I couldn't find a Chrome extension that accepts a list of URLs. I only found extensions that save a screenshot of one open page, not a batch.

Unfortunately, using `--headless` mode and `--screenshot` doesn't allow you to directly specify multiple URLs to capture (as far as I am aware). You will probably need to create a script of some kind to accomplish this goal.

For instance, as brute force method in Windows, you could simply save variations of the appropriate command in a batch (`.bat`) file e.g.:

```
ECHO off

REM A batch file to automate downloading website screenshots

ECHO on

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --screenshot="C:\path\to\screenshot1.png" http://website1.com/

REM More commands here [...]

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --screenshot="C:\path\to\screenshot20.png" http://website20.com/
```

A similar approach using shell scripting would likely work in MacOS as well.

Of course, you can make a script that actually reads a list of URLs (say from a text file) with e.g. batch (Windows), Powershell (Windows), shell scripting (MacOS), Python ([Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and MacOS) or any other options available.

> I need to save thumbnail-sized screenshots of about 20 intranet pages [...] I ruled out installing an application because my office uses both Windows and Mac OS. I didn't want to rely on an application some of us can't install.

I don't think that you will be able to get around a third-party application for this step. Again, `--headless` mode with `--screenshot` doesn't support actually resizing images (just the viewport i.e. window size). Furthermore, Windows doesn't come with a built-in tool to resize images (outside of MS Paint).

As a recommendation, [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org) might be worth looking into as it supports both [Windows and MacOS](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). Once installed, you could simply use e.g.:

```
magick screenshot1.png -resize 50% thumbnail-screenshot1.png
```

to resize an image (although there are many more potential options available).

Note that the command above is for current versions of ImageMagick 7.x+. For legacy versions of ImageMagick, you will likely want to use `convert` in place of `magick` i.e.:

```
convert screenshot1.png -resize 50% thumbnail-screenshot1.png
```

You could make these (or any similar commands) part of the script that captured the screenshots themselves or part of a separate post-processing script.

Comment: Running Chrome from the command line! I didn't know about that. I can use that solution. ImageMagick will help me too.

Answer (score 1):

Also looked for such soft, in the end wrote the script myself
https://github.com/rytsikau/eeScreen

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to [edit] your post to include your script in your answer. Thanks!